# How to create the numpy equivalent to a 1x2 linspace array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

At first i needed an array like this:
`[0.  , 0.25, 0.5 , 0.75, 1.  ]` which is `np.linspace(0,1,5)`. But now I need an array like this:

```py
[[0.  ,  0.],
 [0.25,  0.5],
 [0.5 ,  1.],
 [0.75,  1.5],
 [1.  ,  2]]
```

Note that `array[1][0] != array[1][1]`!

Can't really explain how but it should sort of like this:

```py
array[:][0] = np.linspace(0,1,5)
array[:][1] = np.linspace(0,2,5)
```

Where `array[0][0] is np.linspace(0,1,5)[0]`
and `array[1][0] is np.linspace(0,1,5)[1]`

I hope you kind of understand what array I'm trying to build here.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

np.c_ is the numpy function for this

```
np.c_[np.linspace(0,1,5),np.linspace(0,2,5)]
```

Output:

```
       [0.25, 0.5 ],
       [0.5 , 1.  ],
       [0.75, 1.5 ],
       [1.  , 2.  ]])
```

Comment: Hi, I found this to be a much better solution than the one I originally chose to be the answer!

Answer (score 1):

please notice that your first column is np.linspace(0,1,5) and second one np.linspace(0,2,5) so you can create that array with this two component first make an array from this two with shape 2x5 than when you transpose the array it turns to your 5x2 array:

```
np.array([np.linspace(0,1,5),np.linspace(0,2,5)]).T
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thank you so very much!

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```
In [33]: start = np.array([0, 0])                                                                                     

In [34]: stop = np.array([1, 2])                                                                                      

In [35]: n = 5                                                                                                        

In [36]: np.linspace(0, 1, n).reshape(-1, 1)*(stop - start) + start                                                      
Out[36]: 
array([[0.  , 0.  ],
       [0.25, 0.5 ],
       [0.5 , 1.  ],
       [0.75, 1.5 ],
       [1.  , 2.  ]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You second array is just twice of your first array. So you can also consider the following

```
a = np.linspace(0,1,5)
b = 2*a

np.column_stack((a, b))

# array([[0.  , 0.  ],
#        [0.25, 0.5 ],
#        [0.5 , 1.  ],
#        [0.75, 1.5 ],
#        [1.  , 2.  ]])
```

Alternatively, you can do either

```
np.vstack((a,b)).T
```

OR

```
np.concatenate((a.reshape(5,1), b.reshape(5,1)), axis=1)
```